# Change or Remove OptionMenu in xamarin android

Tags: android, xamarin, optionmenu

I am working on xamarin android application.I have only one MainaActivity and It has three fragments.I want to change MainaActivity's **OptionMenu** and remove some items when fragment is changed.
How to do that?
Any solution!

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You Need to call following method in your MainActivity when you want to change the menu:

```
InvalidateOptionsMenu();
```

That causes the view to reset the options from the activity. That means, the method `OnCreateOptionsMenu` get's called again. Just make some checks in this method like following example:

```
public override bool OnCreateOptionsMenu(IMenu menu)
{
    MenuInflater.Inflate(Resource.Menu.MyMenu, menu);

    var m0 = menu.FindItem(Resource.Id.menuId);
    m0.SetTitle("FirstFragmentAction")
    m0.SetVisible(FirstFragmentActive);

    // And so on
}
```

Android documentation for `InvalidateOptionsMenu`:

> Declare that the options menu has changed, so should be recreated. The
>   onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu) method will be called the next time it needs
>   to be displayed.

Comment: I called ((MainActivity)Activity).InvalidateOptionsMenu (); but still OptionMenu has not removed.

Comment: What are you doing in the `OnCreateOptionsMenu` method?

Comment: In MainActivity I am doing this :                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         `public override bool OnCreateOptionsMenu (IMenu menu) 
  {
   
   MenuInflater.Inflate (Resource.Layout.Menu, menu);
   return true;
  }`

Comment: Ok. So check my answer again. You Need to get your menuitem with `menu.FindItem(Resource.Id.MyMenuItemId);` and then set the visibility depending on what has changed... with that you can remove the items, or at least make it invisible